# Clear browsing history in Firefox with iMacros

Tags: firefox, imacros, browser-history

I want to clear browsing history using iMacros but iMacros's clear command doesn't do enough.

There is the URL:
chrome://browser/content/sanitize.xul
when entered in firefox address bar opens up page to clear everything on press of clear now button. I used iMacros to record it but iMacros is not recording the clicking of Clear Now button.

```
VERSION BUILD=10021450
TAB OPEN
TAB T=2
URL GOTO=chrome://browser/content/sanitize.xul
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=TXT:Clear<SP>Now
```

The TAG line in the code is self written (*Not recorded by iMacros*) and I don't know if this works because on playing the **macros is getting stuck on 4th line**, it is not able to open the URL.
Please help me out

Comment: "CIM" meaning you didn't really check the Wiki nor the iMacros Forum, if you expect any (Advanced) User(s) to try to hep you... - Interesting Qt but you can better open a parallel Thread on the iMacros Forum, I would think... (I don't help 1st time Posters on SOF anymore..., 90% delete their Qt/Thread once they've got their Answer...)

Comment: There is a similar query on iMacros forum but it hasn't been answered so I preferred to post it here.

Comment: I have searched and tried a lot but I cannot get the thing I need. Please help me out and rest assured that I'll not be deleting Qt/Thread.

Comment: + Parallel Thread on the iMacros Forum (where I prefer to answer, can always post the "final' Solution here as well, if any...): https://forum.imacros.net/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=30394&p=82802#p82801